# UICollectionViewController: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Tags: swift, firebase, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, firebase-realtime-database

Reason: 'attempt to insert item 0 into section 1, but there are only 1 sections after the update'

I don't understand what the problem is. If the array is being inserted into section 1 and there is (only) 1 section then why can it not be inserted?

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var messages: [FIRDataSnapshot]! = []
private var refHandle: FIRDatabaseHandle!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Register cell classes
    collectionView?.registerClass(ChatLogCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.messages.removeAll()
    collectionView?.reloadData()
    refHandle = self.ref.child("messages").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
        self.messages.append(snapshot)
        print(self.messages.count) //temp
        self.collectionView?.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.messages.count - 1, inSection: 1)])
    })
}
```

**Cell Code:**

```
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.messages.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChatLogCollectionCell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting something into section `1`, which means there must be `2` sections because numbering starts at `0`.  When iOS checks the consistency of your data by calling `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` which returns `1`, it notes the inconsistency.

Change the section number you are inserting into to `0`.

```
self.collectionView?.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: self.messages.count - 1, inSection: 0)])
```

Comment: You should be using `NSIndexPath(forItem:inSection:)` for collectionViews, although `NSIndexPath(forRow:inSection:)` will return the exact same result.

Comment: This was the final step to fixing a series of bugs that took me days to get to the bottom to, thank you! Also thanks for the additional tip.